# JavaScript FileReader: Save multiple text files' contents to array for later use

Tags: javascript, filereader

I try to save the contents of multiple text files to an array variable using only pure JavaScript. I found some similar questions and answers here on Stackoverflow and tried this and that, without success. Maybe this question is easy to answer, but I'm a beginner, please be tolerant.

Here is my code:

```js
<script>
   fileContents=new Array();

   function getThem(){
      var allFiles=document.getElementById("fileInput").files;

      for(var allFilesCounter=0;allFilesCounter<allFiles.length;allFilesCounter++){

         function readFile(file){
            var reader=new FileReader();

            reader.onload=function(){
               alert(reader.result);
               fileContents[fileContents.length]=reader.result;
            };
            reader.readAsText(file,"UTF-8");
         };
      };
   };
</script>

<input type="file" accept="text/plain" id="fileInput" multiple="multiple" onChange="getThem();">
```

I already found out that the FileReader works "asynchronous", which seems to require that all processing of the file content is done inside the reader.onload-function. "alert" does work, as well as other processing, but not assigning the content to the global variable, that's "fileContents[fileContents.length]" in my case.

Is it achievable with that rather simple code, or should I accept that it is not possible to get the file contents saved to a variable (which seems to me to be the most simple and elegant way, but probably I'm wrong).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right path but you created the function `readFile` and didn't make a call to it, that is why you were not getting the file contents, but the function is unnecessary. Bellow there is a working snippet with a simpler code, hope you can understand it.

```js
var fileContents = [];

document.getElementById('fileInput').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect);

function handleFileSelect (e) {
    var allFiles = e.target.files;
    for (var i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e) {
            alert(e.target.result);
            fileContents.push(e.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(allFiles[i]);
    };
};
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="text/plain" id="fileInput" multiple="multiple" />
```